# How do I make the object rotate only from the right with the lerp command?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a spin code. With this code, I want to rotate the object 313 degrees to the right.
But the lerp command rotates 47(360-313) degrees from the left.
I guess it does it because it's closer to turn from the left.
But I want it to turn right. I never want it to turn left. How do i get this?

[image]

My spin code:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0,313,0), 3f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split up the code and only lerp the Y variable. After that you could just directly set `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,angle,0)`.

Something like this should be sufficient (Not tested):

```
var rotY = Mathf.Lerp(currentY, targetY, Time.deltaTime * 3f);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, 0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. The bottle vibrated constantly and failed to show the target